# Как сделать такую функцию vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

На странице есть иконка, при наведение на нее, она исчезает и вместо нее появляется input:

```
<header id="header">
   <div class="uk-navbar-right">
         <ion-icon @mouseover="show=true" v-show="mouse2" name="search" size="large"></ion-icon>                
         <form action="#" @blur="show=false">
            <div class="uk-inline">
                <ion-icon v-show="mouse" v-bind:class="{{@style}}" name="search" size="large"></ion-icon>
                <input v-show="show" type="text" class="uk-input" placeholder="{{ @message }}">    
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</header>
<script>
        new Vue({
            el:"#header",
            data:{
                message: "Hello World",
                show: false,
                mouse: false,
                mouse2: true,
                style: "uk-form-icon uk-form-icon-flip"
            },
            methods:{
                mouseover: function(){
                    this.show = !this.show
                    this.mouse = !this.mouse
                    this.mouse2 = !this.mouse2
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
```

А как сделать, чтоб при наведение на иконку появлялся input и после того как курсор будет убран с Input'а через 2сек опять появлялась иконка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотри, тебе нужно событие повесить на `.uk-navbar-right`

```
<header id="header">
  <div class="uk-navbar-right" @mouseover="onMouseover" @mouseout="onMouseout">
    <ion-icon v-if="!show" name="search" size="large"></ion-icon>                
    <form action="#" v-else>
      <div class="uk-inline">
        <ion-icon v-show="mouse" v-bind:class="{{@style}}" name="search" size="large"></ion-icon>
        <input v-show="show" type="text" class="uk-input" placeholder="{{ @message }}">    
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</header>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el:"#header",
        data:{
            message: "Hello World",
            show: false,
            mouse: false,
            mouse2: true,
            style: "uk-form-icon uk-form-icon-flip"
        },
        methods:{
            onMouseover: function(){
                clearTimeout(this._timer)
                this.show = true
            },
            onMouseout: function(){
                clearTimeout(this._timer)
                var self = this
                this._timer = setTimeout(function(){
                    self.show = false
                },2000)
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Если что-то непонятно, задай уточняющий вопрос

Comment: Вот щас пытаюсь сделать анимированный переход, то есть при наведение на иконку input просто появляется, а хочу сделать, чтоб он выдвигался как-бы из иконки. Для этого я добавляю атрибут transition div.uk-inline, и в css файле пишу вот такие свойства: `.slide-transition{
 -webkit-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.65,.05,.36,1);
 transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.65,.05,.36,1);
}
.slide-enter{
 left:-100%;
}
.slide-leave{
 left:-100%;
}`  Но не помогает, поле просто появляется и все..

Comment: Главное вопрос решен))

Comment: Почитай доки по переходам в Vue https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html
И вообще, когда, полный guide прочитаешь, то сможешь сделать все, что задумал))